# Movies of the past

Tags: story-identification

30's, 40's story of 2 guys who invent a movie camera that can film the past.  Their movies of the Roman Empire, the Civil War and the Life of Christ cause riots.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_religious_ideas_in_science_fiction#Jesus

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116433/scifi-book-where-machine-invented-to-allow-viewing-into-the-past/116470?

Comment: Book?  Movie?  Short story?  TV show?

Comment: @WadCheber - Webisode? Play? Phenakistoscope? Praxinoscope?

Comment: Was my answer the right one?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171918/1950s-short-story-about-using-radar-to-see-into-the-past-and-filming-historic-ev (which is newer and has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

Possibly this is the 1947 short story "[E for Effort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_for_Effort)", as noted in [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116437/20774).

> Taking place at some time in the near future (relative to when it was written), the story is briefly framed as a manuscript delivered to a civilian by the military under circumstances of great tension.
>
> The manuscript is a long letter to "Joe", apparently a bartender, by Ed Lefko. He describes seeing a silent but color movie aimed at Mexican-Americans in a run-down theater in Detroit. The movie recounts Cortés's conquest of Mexico with remarkably realistic sets and acting and a huge cast. The projectionist, a World War II veteran named Miguel "Mike" Laviada, tells Ed that h**e made the movie using a time viewer he invented**, which he demonstrates. However, **Mike has not been able to raise the capital** needed to shoot the picture on high-quality film, add sound and other improvements, and get it distributed and advertised. He and Ed become partners, and at Ed's suggestion, they **raise money by using the machine to blackmail wealthy people**.
>
> They spend a year making most of a new film out of time-viewed footage of Alexander the Great. They **take it to Hollywood**, where the high quality of the film easily convinces a producer and his associates to finish it, including using actors for scenes that appear in Alexander's biographies but did not really happen, and market it. The film is a great success with critics and viewers.

....

> Ed and Mike admit the machine's existence to their associates and persuade them to join in their **plan to expose the corruption of many famous people involved in the wars**. The film causes riots in many countries and greatly increases international hostility.

Comment: *Another answer* ... which I've [shamelessly ripped off](https://allthethingsinbetween.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Menace-Mustache.jpg). Ahahahahahahahaha!

Comment: ^_^ At least you credited it.