# SF short story from the 1970s, maybe earlier where two men start a movie company showing real footage of historical events

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I **THINK** this was by Robert Heinlein. In the story two men have/develop a device that can show video of the past. They start a movie company and hire a young woman who I THINK develops a romance with one of them. The movie company becomes famous for its spectacles/epic movies. "Casts" of thousands when it's actually the REAL EVENT — famous battles from history. Then they make a movie about Jesus, and the excrement impacts the air recirculation impeller. Oops. There's a trial, and I forget what the reason for that is, but in the trial, they demonstrate that they can show the past, ANY TIME IN THE PAST, by showing the judge a video of his honeymoon with his, I think, dead wife. I forget what leads to the actual end, but it's in the form of telegrams or news flashes, but the actual end of the story is a nuclear war.

Comment: Do [any of these Jesus time-travel questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btime-travel%5D+jesus+is%3Aq) ring a bell?

Comment: See OP confirmation comment for answer below.

Comment: I would look at Harry Harrison. I seem to recall a book called chnicsomething like "The Technicolor Time Machine" that might fit your question.

Answer (score 19):

This sounds like "[E for Effort](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45679)" (1947) by T.L. Sherred.

The protagonist, Ed, discovers that Mike has created a machine that allows him to film movies through time.  They create a movie of Alexander the Great, which is a huge success, and move on to ever more recent wars.

They hire a young woman as a secretary:

> We had the windows sealed, a flossy office installed in the front—the bulletproof glass was my idea—air conditioning, a portable bar, electrical wiring of whatever type Mike’s little heart desired, and a blond secretary who thought she was working for M-E Experimental Laboratories.

They also remove anything to do with Christ from the feature they do on the fall of Rome, but not by choice:

> The criticism we drew for almost ignoring Christ and Christianity was unjust, we think, and unfair. Very few knew then, or know now, that we had included, as a kind of trial balloon, some footage of Christ Himself, and His times. This footage we had to cut. The Board of Review, as you know, is both Catholic and Protestant. They—the Board—went right up in arms. We didn't protest very hard when they claimed our "treatment" was irreverent, indecent, and biased and inaccurate "by any Christian standard. Why," they wailed, "it doesn't even look like Him," and they were right; it didn't. Not any picture *they* ever saw.

Ed muses that he almost got together with Ruth, their secretary, but didn't:

> For awhile I had a few ideas about her that might have developed into something serious. We both—I should say, all three of us—found out in time that we looked at a lot of things too differently.

They mostly do okay with the U.S. Civil War, though some people don't like it:

> The next two pictures we released in rapid succession; the first "Freedom for Americans," the American Revolution, and "The Brothers and the Guns," the American Civil War. Bang! Every third politician, a lot of so-called “educators,” and all the professional patriots started after our scalps. Every single chapter of the DAR, the Sons of Union Veterans, and the Daughters of the Confederacy pounded their collective heads against the wall.

But when they get to the World Wars, where some of the people whose crimes they can reveal are still alive, the government comes down on them:

> I wonder how many prints of that picture are left today. I wonder how many escaped burning or confiscation. Two World Wars we covered, covered from the unflattering angles that, up until then, had been represented by only a few books hidden in the dark corners of libraries. We showed and named the war-makers, the cynical ones who signed and laughed and lied, the blatant patriots who used the flare of headlines and the ugliness of atrocity to hide behind their flag while life turned to death for millions.

There is a scene where they show a judge a view of a day in his life to demonstrate the machine is recording actual history:

> He thought. Seconds. Minutes. The tension twanged, and I swallowed dust. He spoke quietly. "1918. November 11th."
>
> Mike whispered to me. I said, "Any particular time?"
>
> Justice Bronson looked at Mike. 'Exactly eleven. Armistice time." He paused, then went on. "Niagara Falls. Niagara Falls, New York."

Ed and Mike get locked up, the government seizes the machine, and knowledge that the U.S. government has a machine that can compromise all secrets triggers a nuclear war:

> BEGINS: Area Detroit Savings Bank vaporized direct hit. Radioactivity lethal. Impossible boxes or any contents survive. Repeat, direct hit. Request permission proceed Washington Area. ENDS.

The story was originally published in *Astounding*, May 1947, and has been frequently anthologised.  You can read it at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v39n03_1947-05_AK/page/n118/mode/1up).

Comment: OP is probably recalling this part: Very few knew then, or know now, that we had included, as a kind of trial balloon, some footage of Christ Himself, and His times. This footage we had to cut. The Board of Review, as you know, is both Catholic and Protestant. They—the Board—went right up in arms. We didn't protest very hard when they claimed our "treatment" was irreverent, indecent, and biased and inaccurate "by any Christian standard."

Comment: There are a large number of questions about this one on the site already.

Comment: Yes, it is, indeed, "E for Effort" by T.L. Sherrad, 1947. And I am remembering it correctly that there was a section on a film made about the life and times of Jesus. But thank you one and all for helping out an old dude who has the beginnings of a failing memory.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171918/1950s-short-story-about-using-radar-to-see-into-the-past-and-filming-historic-ev/171923#171923 looks like the current topper.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I was mobile when I answered this, but I can improve it with some quotes now if you want to wait.

Comment: @DavidW: :-D Not the querent, but I'm always happy to see a good answer get better.